# Passing an array of chars to a function

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, char, character-arrays

I have this code. I am trying to pass a character array to a function and I get an  error saying:

> "Expected primary expression before the ']' token " at line 21

on which I call the function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

char* mostFrequentWord(int, char [][10]);

int main()
{

    int br = 0, n, br1 = 0;

    char str[100][10];

    cin >> n;
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        cout << " cin >> str"<< i << "= ";
        cin>> str[i];
    }

    cout << mostFrequentWord(n, str[][10]) <<endl;

    int m;
    for(int i=0; i<n-1; ++i)
    {
        for(int j=i+1; j<n; ++j)
        {
            if(!strcmp(str[i],str[j]))
            {
                ++br;
            }
        }
        if(br>br1)
        {
            br1 = br;
            m = i;
        }
    }

    cout << str[m] <<endl;
    return 0;
}
char* mostFrequentWord(int n, char str[][10])
{
    int m, br = 0, br1 = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<n-1; ++i)
    {
        for(int j=i+1; j<n; ++j)
        {
            if(!strcmp(str[i],str[j]))
            {
                ++br;
            }
        }
        if(br>br1)
        {
            br1 = br;
            m = i;
        }
    }
    return str[m];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
cout << mostFrequentWord(n, str[][10]) <<endl;
```

needs to read

```
cout << mostFrequentWord(n, str) <<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You answer is in your question:. Just pass the **str**.

```
cout << mostFrequentWord(n, str) <<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the function this way

```
mostFrequentWord(n,str)
```

This should work. Rest of the code is fine.